# How do I use shape keys and bones for a Facial Rig?

Tags: rigging

I want to try my hand at a more advanced facial rig but I'm nout sure how to go about it

Comment: Hello. Could you please elaborate which part of the workflow you are having difficulties with? Perhaps show images of what you got so far so it is easier to help you

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you have more information to add, edit the first one.